# Within Visual Studio Code PowerShell keeps hanging when logging into Azure with Connect-AzAccount

Tags: powershell

In the terminal of Visual Studio Code(installed on Ubuntu) i try to use "Connect-AzAccount" to login to Azure. It looks like in the background PowerShell is busy (maybe with MFA) but no new pop up appears.

Any idea what to do?

[image]

I have installed the following extensions:

- PowerShell (ms-vscode.powershell)
- Azure CLI Tools (ms-vscode.azurecli)
- Python (ms-python.python)
- Jupyter (ms-toolsai.jupyter)

**$PSVersionTable**

Name                           Value

---

PSVersion                      7.1.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.1.1
OS                             Linux 5.4.0-65-generic #73~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 19 09:02:24 UTC 2021
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

Comment: Some advice before it gets lost.. please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66108385/edit) your question and put the extra info you have now posted as answers in  there. Because they're not **answers**, it won't take long before they are deleted..

Answer (score 0):

without changing anything it now works for me it seems with the following message:

WARNING: INITIALIZATION: Fallback context save mode to process because of error during checking token cache persistence: Could not get access to the shared lock file..
Opening in existing browser session.

Answer (score 0):

via "az login" there is no issue

Opening in existing browser session.
You have logged in. Now let us find all the subscriptions to which you have access...